# Query builder in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I'm trying to do a query within a model, then call it in the url with

```
namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class TeachingPoint extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

protected $with = ['testRelation'];

public function testRelation()
{
      $table = DB::table('test_table')->where(xxxx)->->get();
      foreach($table as $data)
      {
        etc...
      }
      return $data;
}
```

I need to do it on the model, is this possible? Or I have to do it with "attribute" or in the controller itself

Thank you

Comment: You have to return the data to the controller and then call the url.

Comment: All relations **must** return a `$query` object in order to be eager loaded. As written your `$with = ['testRelation']` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write 
Use DB;
as it is define in your app.php 
and more thing do correct your code 
$table = DB::table('test_table')->where(xxxx)->->get(); not
$table = DB::table('test_table')->where(xxxx)->get();
it will definitely work